# Write Python cloud functions to manipulate data stored on Datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, datastore

I've stored some records on my datastore console. Now I wanna manipulate them to optimize Big Data analytics. 
How can I write a Python cloud routine to make some transformations on my data? Can I trigger it with Datastore events?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a little bit myself. You can find [my code in GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Entities-Python/cf_datastore_update_python.py).

**What it is doing:**

- It is an HTTP Cloud Function
- Establishing connection to Google Cloud Datastore through `client()`
- Updates a value of specific entry in the entity using ID number and entry's column name

**How to use:**

Test this Cloud Function and get the idea of how it is working. Then manipulate according to your needs. I have tested this my self and it is working.

1. Create an HTTP trigger Python Cloud Function.
2. Set the name to `updateDatastore`
3. Copy and paste [the code from GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Entities-Python/cf_datastore_update_python.py).
4. Add this line `google-cloud-datastore` to the `requirements.txt` file.
5. In main code assign ENTITY_KIND your entity's kind value
6. In main code assign ENTITY_KEY your entity's key value
7. When clicked on HTTP trigger URL, after your Cloud Function's execution current time will be written in the column.